# Thread sleep as a benchmark

Tags: java, benchmarking, thread-sleep

Is using `Thread.sleep` as a benchmark procedure generally good idea? Are there some resources giving reasons?

What I'm trying to do is to measure speedup of library I implemented. Given set of tasks (`Runnables`) I measure `t1 =` walltime  of their execution. Afterwards, I execute them parallelly using my library - again measuring walltime `t2`. Let speedup be simply fraction `t1/t2`.

I wonder what tasks should I use for correct measurement. So far, I tried `Thread.sleep(20)` and computation of fibonacci numbers. Results gave significantly different speedups.

According to `The Art Of Computer Systems Performance Analysis`, it is important for tasks to have reasonable instruction mix. However, the book covers general field of study, leaving parallelization aside. Hence I assume that since I measure speedup (relative quantity), I don't need to worry about it.

From this point of view, `Thread.sleep` is perfect task routine as it doesn't consume CPU time. However, I've read a lot of posts discouraging from this technique, suggesting real computation instead.

So the question(s): Should one use `Thread.sleep` in order to obtain correct speedup results? If not, what other routines are acceptable and why (possibly providing whitepapers or other publications)?

Note: `Thread.sleep` from Java is only an example, the problem is language-independent.

Comment: For example you have 2 cores, and you run parallel 20 tasks with real consumption, each take 10s, you will end up with total execution of 20*10s / 2 cores = 100 seconds. If you use thread sleep for 10s, you will end up with 10s total execution, because all 20 tasks can be slept at same time. Im not expert, so I dont add this as an answer x)

Comment: But next task is executed only after some thread is free, which is after some previous task have finished, doesn't it? Internally I use FixedThreadPool, that, i believe, works like that.

Comment: Add tag -java- if we talking about that language.  You have right I think. But what about other threads in application that are not in thread pool? What about critical sections? I think only real consumption can show real performance benefits.